# Fill a shape with an unknown amount of copy to produce SVG

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svg, graphics

Really appreciate any advice here as this must be the first time in years I haven't been able to either figure it out with my team here, or find an answer online.

The challenge set is that we need to create a shape, for arguments sake lets say the United Kingdom.  An end user through our web interface should then be able to upload an unknown amount of copy via a text file, and we then need to resize it (up or down) to fill that area without any cropping.

The resulting output is then fed back to the user as an SVG.

Again, I really appreciate any advice anyone can give?

John

Comment: Thanks for your response!  We got pretty close with Illustrator running on the server but it was just far too slow.  We have been trying to work out how to do it programmatically but there are always different problems.  When we try and do it line by line, that doesn't work because we need multiple amounts of lines depending on the amount of copy.  Using tag-cloud style techniques doesn't help because of the requirement for consistent font size.  We got close with just cropping copy but of course that is contrary to the requirements.  I guess at this stage we just hope it's possible!

Comment: create a [mcve] showing some really simple map rather than the UK with your attempt to fill it in the way you want. Include some pictures of how you would actually want this to look like.

Comment: Just a hint: Inkscape implements a [Text in a Shape](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Flow.html) command that can be accessed in a shell via its [verb](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html#verb-VERB-ID---select-OBJECT-ID) syntax as `ObjectFlowText` and `ObjectFlowtextToText`. Since this also opens the GUI, you might run into the same performance issues as with Illustrator.